# Way to get num of users connected Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat

I am programming a chat with Node. Everything is almost done. There are diferrents chatrooms. Example: if someone is in the Room 1  only will get message from this room. But  I'd like to know the best way to get the users connected in this room (only this room).

I had thought about two ways but I am not sure if they are the best options.1. to have in the server an array of all users connected by room. 2. when an user connect to the room to add this user to the database and get these users connected when rendering the room. and when they disconnect remove from the db.

In some way the 2 option is the same than the first only that the array is in the db.
what other way would you suggest?
I'm using mongoose and socket.io.

```
      io.of('/chatroom').on('connection',function(socket) {

       socket.on('join',function(data) {

        db.roomModel.findById(data.roomId,function(err,room) {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(room) {
                // I am storing the users connected in that room
                // in the database 
                room.connections.push({userId : data.userId});
                room.save();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Then when the user disconnect I remove it from the database.
Is it recommended to do so in that way.

Comment: Show us some code, how do you expect to get help without showing what you already done?

Comment: I think you should try out http://socket.io/

Comment: Sorry for not showing some code. I have done. I hope you can help me